# Excel VBA worksheetfunction Index Match with an Array

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, match, worksheet-function

Is there a way to get VBA to except Array formulas with INDEX MATCH when using a .worksheetfunction?

My first formula works since it's not an array I presume?

This code works

```
Dim VType As string
VType = Application.WorksheetFunction.Index(Sheets(sheetname).Range("$B:$B"), Application.WorksheetFunction.Match("*" & VendorCode & "*", Sheets(sheetname).Range("$A:$A"), 0), 1)
```

But then when I add a 2nd match I get an arror: **Type mismatch**

```
Dim RetORWaste As String
RetORWaste = Application.WorksheetFunction.Index(Sheets(wsMaster.Name).Range("$F:$F"), Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(("*" & VendorCode & "*") & ("*" & VRegion & "*"), (Sheets(wsMaster.Name).Range("$B:$B")) & (Sheets(wsMaster.Name).Range("$C:$C")), 0), 1)
```

Both sheetname and wsMaster.name are string.
The wsMaster.Name also gets the correct sheetname. So it must be the array?

Comment: `(Sheets(wsMaster.Name).Range("$B:$B")) & (Sheets(wsMaster.Name).Range("$C:$C"))` is trying to concatenate two arrays... which you can't do and will throw a type mismatch. You could use `Evaluate` here.

Comment: @BigBen I've seen a few posts online where people use `evaluate` but not sure where in the formula to add it in my case?

Comment: You just `RetORWaste = wsMaster.Evaluate("yourformulaasastringminustheleadingequals")`

Comment: `DCcol = wsMaster.Evaluate("Index(Sheets(wsMaster.Name).Range("$D:$D"), Match(("*" & VendorCode & "*") & ("*" & VRegion & "*"), (Sheets(wsMaster.Name).Range("$B:$B")) & (Sheets(wsMaster.Name).Range("$C:$C")), 0), 1)")` This is what I've changed it to. First it had an problem with the `$` sign syaing it's an invalid caracter, and then gives an error Syntax error. Sorry I'm probably enetering it wrong, I've not used 'evaluate' before

Comment: "yourformulaasastring" - the way you would type it in a worksheet, not as VBA: `"INDEX('Master'!D:D,MATCH(...)"`...

Comment: @BigBen the problem is that I have variables in there. I need to use them since they change every week...

Comment: Then concatenate them in with `&`.

Comment: Can you better explain what you wish to accomplish using the second way? If the `Match` will not exist in column `B:B`, to be find in `C:C`? I am afraid that this cannot be done even if using `Evaluate`. There are not arrays. The functions uses `Ranges` and the result is return according to the range `Row` index. Unfortunately, `Match` function returns an error if not a match found and a helper function and a `IIf` function must be used, I think... If my above assumption is correct I can post a piece of code doing what you need, but only for the sake of doing everything in one row...

Comment: @FaneDuru There will always be a match, so that won't be an issue. I'm quickly adjusting my formula as BigBen mentioned above to see if it works.

Comment: I wish you good luck! But you did not answer my question regarding the need of two ranges to be used for Match. If my assumption that your intention is to Match the search string in first Range and Match it in the second one, if not a match exist in first, can you explain why are you using both of them? Thanks in advance!

Comment: @BigBen I have done as you suggested. Added the variables in the '&'. **Object doesn't support this property or method**. This is what the code looks like now `RetORWaste = wsMaster.Evaluate("Index(" & Sheets(wsMaster.Name) & "F:F,Match(" & VendorCode & "&" & VRegion & "," & Sheets(wsMaster.Name) & "B:B&" & Sheets(wsMaster.Name) & "C:C,0),1)")`

Comment: You just want `wsMaster.Name`... no `Sheets` calls.

Comment: @bigben realized that as soon as I commented sorry. I'm getting an error **type mismatch** now when `sheets` are removed

Comment: Your syntax still seems off... you need `!` between the sheet names and the columns, and possibly `'` around the sheet name as well. Highly suggest you `Debug.Print` the entire string to make sure it is what you expect, so that you could add an `=` in front of it and use it as a formula in a cell.

Comment: @BigBen just added the `'` and '!', but still getting a **type mismatch** error. I'll debug print quickly. I don't know if it makes any difference, but I'm not going to use it in a cell. I save it to the string variable `RetORWaste` to reference to in the code

Comment: I know you're not going to use it in a cell, but it has to be exactly the same as if you were.

Comment: @BigBen: Shouldn't it be simpler to write the correct string for him? I would be very surprised to see it working... And full of admiration, too. :)

Comment: @FaneDuru - perhaps... but I'm trying to "teach a man to fish." (Give a man a fish, and you'll feed him for a day. Teach a man to fish, and you've fed him for a lifetime.") haha.

Comment: You're doing too much in one line - break it up into multiple lines and use some variables.

Comment: @BigBen: I had such a supposition, but I must confess I am skeptic regarding the result in the recommended way... I am just anxious to see it. :)

Comment: @BigBen, The string is as expected. Did a manual calculation in a cell to check, and they match. Am I missing something? The code line: `RetORWaste = wsMaster.Evaluate("Index('" & wsMaster.Name & "'!F:F,Match(" & VendorCode & "&" & VRegion & ",'" & wsMaster.Name & "'!B:B&'" & wsMaster.Name & "'!C:C,0),1)")` and then the Debug.print string without the `wsMaster.Evaluate` is `Index('06.12.2019'!F:F,Match(1000002699&Eastern Cape,'06.12.2019'!B:B&'06.12.2019'!C:C,0),1)` and line from the manual formula `=index('06.12.2019'!F:F,MATCH(1000002699&Eastern Cape,'06.12.2019'!B:B&'06.12.2019'!C:C,0,1)`

Comment: @BigBen thanks for the help. The solution from Tim below works. I do appreciate you trying to teach me rather than just give me the answer. I would rather learn than just be *fed*. Still not sure why the long string doesn't work. But atleast the solution works for now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I'm understanding correctly that you want to do a "two column match" as here:  https://www.excel-easy.com/examples/two-column-lookup.html

```
Sub tester()

    Dim RetORWaste As String, wsMaster As Worksheet, m, f
    Dim VendorCode, VRegion

    Set wsMaster = ActiveSheet

    VendorCode = "A"
    VRegion = "B"

    f = "=MATCH(""*{vend}*""&""*{region}*"",B:B&C:C,0)"
    f = Replace(f, "{vend}", VendorCode)
    f = Replace(f, "{region}", VRegion)

    m = wsMaster.Evaluate(f) '<<do not use Application.Evaluate here, or the
                             '  formula will evaluate in the context of the 
                             '  active sheet, which might not be wsMaster

    If Not IsError(m) Then
        'got a match so get the value from col F
        RetORWaste = wsMaster.Cells(m, "F")
        Debug.Print RetORWaste
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: It works!! Thank you very much. I did try splitting the formula before, using replace. But I was either doing it wrong, or the array was causing problems. I'm still learning a lot about VBA code... Thank you very much!

Comment: No problem.  FYI I don't think you can do this particular lookup using `Application.Match` - you need to use the `Evaluate` method.

Comment: From all the posts I read, `evaluate` always seemed to be the solution for array formulas. But when the variables and multiple formulas get combined I guess it gets a bit tricky.

Comment: The issue with this particular case is the `&` can't be applied when using `WorksheetFunction.Match` - it only works in a formula on the worksheet.